# JEST testPathPattern not recognizing integration tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs, visual-web-developer-2010

I have the below structure and trying to run `jest --testPathPattern=static/integration-tests` to execute only the integration-tests. But I am seeing 0 matches. I tried even `testRegex` and other options too but in vain. Is my command right or is any modification required? FYI jest documentation doesn't have much description on the file patterns and I am completely new to the `Javascript` and ofcourse the `Jest`. Appreciate any help!

```
-resources
   |__package.json
   |__static
          |__unit-tests
          |          |__somescript.unit.test.js
          |
          |__integration-tests
                     |__somescript.int.test.js
```

Comment: Your command should work as you expect. Could it be that you have a jest configuration (either in your package.json or in a separate file) that is adding additional configuration to filter out your test?

Comment: @mgarcia There is no additional config file. Below is the package.json script content and I would appreciate if you can provide me any working solution. "scripts":{
"integration-test": "jest --testPathPattern=static/integration-tests",
"unit-test":"jest"
}

Comment: I don't know about any online editor that support changing package.json file. If you know where I can provide a working solution, I would be happy to oblige.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a file naming scheme to distinguish unit and integration tests like you, this works for me:

`jest --testRegex '\\.(?:unit)\\.test.js$'`

`jest --testRegex '\\.(?:int)\\.test.js$'`

or if you want to run more than one kind of test:

`jest --testRegex '\\.(?:unit|int)\\.test.js$'`